Solve for $y$ in $ye^{\frac{1}{2}(y-\frac{1}{y})}=x$
I'd like to solve the following equation for $y$ in terms of $x$
$$ye^{\frac{1}{2}(y-\frac{1}{y})}=x$$
This equation is close in nature to the definition of the Lambert $W$ function, but different enough that it is not clear how to use it to solve for $y$. Any help with this would be very appreciated.

@ТymaGaidash Thank you for making me aware of that question. In your answer to that question, could you explain how you simplified the Laplace transform of $h(t)$? In particular, how did you write the integrand purely in terms of $f(t)$?

Of course, there may be other solutions to the equation, but you can substitute $h(t)\to t$ in the integral. Here is a more concise comment: $y=e^w\implies e^{\sinh(w)+w}=x$ and use this. Maybe we can comment on it in the answer itself.

If you have a better estimate use it as $a$ in my answer.

Considering $x>0$ the equation is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
{\log\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}+\frac{1}{2}(y-\frac{1}{y})=0
\end{equation}
Transforming the equation with the change of variable $y\rightarrow1-1/z$ and multiplying by z, we obtain the equation
\begin{equation}
z\log\left(\frac{1}{x}\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)\right)+\frac{1-2z}{2\left(z-1\right)}=0
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
2z(z-1)\log\left(\frac{1}{x}\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)\right)+1-2z=0
\end{equation}
Defining the function $f(z)=2z(z-1)\log\left(\frac{1}{x}\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)\right)+1-2z$ and applying the Burniston-Siewert method to solve transcendental
equations to this equation we obtain
\begin{equation}
y=1-\frac{1}{z_{0}},\quad z_{0}=\frac{\log\left(x\right)-4}{2\log\left(x\right)}+m
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
m=\frac{1}{\pi}{\displaystyle \int\limits _{0}^{1}}\arctan\left[\frac{1-2t}{2\pi t(t-1)}+\frac{1}{\pi}\log\left(\frac{1-t}{xt}\right)\right]\,dt
\end{equation}
(Another representation is)
\begin{equation}
m=\frac{1}{\pi}{\displaystyle \int\limits _{-\infty}^{\infty}}\frac{e^{t}}{\left(1+e^{t}\right)^{2}}\arctan\left[\frac{t-\sinh\left(t\right)-\log\left(x\right)}{\pi}\right]\,dt
\end{equation}
Putting everything into a single expression, the inverse for the function $f(y)=ye^{\frac{1}{2}(y-\frac{1}{y})}$ is
\begin{equation}
f^{-1}(x)=1-\left[\frac{\log\left(x\right)-4}{2\log\left(x\right)}+\frac{1}{\pi}{\displaystyle \int\limits _{0}^{1}}\arctan\left[\frac{1-2t}{2\pi t(t-1)}+\frac{1}{\pi}\log\left(\frac{1-t}{xt}\right)\right]\,dt\right]^{-1}
\end{equation}
With this expression an approximation for values ​​close to 1 will be
$$ \begin{align} f^{-1}(x) &  \sim 1-\left[\frac{\log\left(x\right)-4}{2\log\left(x\right)}+\frac{1}{\pi}{\displaystyle \int\limits _{0}^{1}}\frac{1-2t}{2\pi t(t-1)}+\frac{1}{\pi}\log\left(\frac{1-t}{xt}\right)\,dt\right]^{-1}
\\ & \sim1-\left[\frac{\log\left(x\right)-4}{2\log\left(x\right)}+\frac{1}{\pi}{\displaystyle \int\limits _{0}^{1}}\frac{1}{\pi}\log\left(\frac{1-t}{xt}\right)\,dt\right]^{-1}  \\ & \sim 1-\left[\frac{\log\left(x\right)-4}{2\log\left(x\right)}-\frac{\log\left(x\right)}{\pi^{2}}\right]^{-1} \end{align} $$
then
\begin{equation}
f^{-1}(x)\sim\frac{\pi^{2}\left(4+\log\left(x\right)\right)+2\log^{2}\left(x\right)}{\pi^{2}\left(4-\log\left(x\right)\right)+2\log^{2}\left(x\right)}\quad\textrm{if}\,\,x\rightarrow1
\end{equation}
For example, for $x=1.01$ the inverse gives us
\begin{equation}
x=1.004987551798...
\end{equation}
and the approach
\begin{equation}
x=\color{red} {1.0049875}47346...
\end{equation}
Ref:
-E. E. Burniston, C.E. Siewert. The use of Riemann problems in solving a class of transcendental equations. Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society. 73. 111 - 118. (1973).
-Henrici P., Applied and computational complex analysis, Volume III. Wiley, New York. 183-191 (1986).

Assuming $x>0$, we have a first estimate given by
$$y\,e^{y/2}=x \quad \implies \quad y_0=2\, W\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$ which will be better and better with increasing $x$.
Consider the function
$$f(y)=y\,e^{\frac{1}{2}
   \left(y-\frac{1}{y}\right)}-x$$ whose first and second derivatives are positive.
Since $f(y_0)$ is negative, by Darboux theorem, $y_0$ is  an under estimate of the solution.
Now, since numerical methods will be required, I think that is would be better to consider that we look for the zero of function
$$g(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(y-\frac{1}{y}\right)+\log (y)-\log(x)$$ which is closer to linearity.
$$g'(y)=\frac{(y+1)^2}{2 y^2}$$
So, a better estimate is (Newton method)
$$y_1=y_0-\frac {g(y_0)}{g'(y_0)}$$
Trying for $x=123$ and converting to decimals
$$y_0=6.03066\quad \implies \quad y_1= 6.15266$$ while the solution is $y=6.15301$.
In fact, you can have explicit formulae using the first iterate of Newton-like methods of order $n$.
Repeating the example for various $n$ and converting to decimals
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & y_1^{(n)} &  \text{method}\\
 2 &  6.15266049028 & \text{Newton}\\
 3 &  6.15301256641 & \text{Halley}\\
 4 &  6.15300846994 & \text{Householder}\\
 5 &  6.15300852649 & \text{no name}\\
 6 &  6.15300852563 & \text{no name}\\
 7 &  6.15300852565 & \text{no name}\\
\end{array}
\right)$$
If you prefer a series solution, expand the function around $a=y_0$
$$g(y)=\frac{1}{2} \left(a-\frac{1}{a}+2 \log
   (a)\right)+\frac{(a+1)^2}{2 a^2}\,(y-a)+$$ $$\frac 1{2a}\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\,\frac {n+2a}{n\,a^n }\, (y-a)^n \tag 1$$
Use power series reversion to obtain
$$\large\color{blue}{y=a +\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \,\frac{a^{n+1}}{(a+1)^{3 n-1} }\,P_n(a)\, t^n} \tag 2$$ where
$$a=2\, W\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \quad \text{and} \quad t=\frac{1-a^2}{2 a}+\log\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$$ The very first polynomials are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P_n(a) \\
 1 & -2 \\
 2 & 4 \\
 3 & \frac{8}{3} (2 a-3) \\
 4 & \frac{8}{3} \left(3 a^2-11 a+6\right) \\
 5 & \frac{32}{15} \left(6 a^3-38 a^2+51 a-15\right) \\
 6 & \frac{32}{45} \left(30 a^4-282
   a^3+661 a^2-477 a+90\right) \\
 7 & \frac{128}{315} \left(90 a^5-1152
   a^4+4054 a^3-5121 a^2+2358
   a-315\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Since we know all coefficients in $(1)$, we also know all coefficients in $(2)$ using the explicit formula for the $n^{\text{th}}$ term as  given by Morse and Feshbach.
Using the above for the test case where $x=123$ gives
$$y=\color{red}{6.15300852564510}726$$
