analytic solution to $x \exp (poly(x)) =$ const
I am looking for a solution to the equation $x\, \exp(poly(x)) = c$ for some polynomial $poly(x)$ in $x$ and a real number $c$.
We know that the Lambert $W$-function provides an analytical solution to $x \, \exp (x) = c$ as $x=W(c)= \sum_n \frac{(-n)^{n-1}}{n!} c^n$ (I am leaving out the existence of branches to keep things simpler).
We can also go one step further and solve equations with non-matching exponents in $x.$ As an example, we pick $x \exp(x^2)= c$, and we first square both sides of the equation and the multiply by 2, namely obtaining
\begin{equation}
 2x^2 \exp (2 x^2) = 2 c^2 \ ,
\end{equation}
and finally we substitute $y=2x^2$ to apply the $W$-function.
But what if we now have a polynomial in the exponential, e.g.
\begin{equation}
 x \exp(x+x^2) = c \ ,
\end{equation}
does this equation have a (non-numerical) solution? If yes, can completely generalize the solution to an expression of the form
\begin{equation}
 x \exp(a_1x+a_2x^2+...+a_N x^N) = c \ ?
\end{equation}

The equation $\text{poly}(x)e^x=c$ has this arxiv solution, so maybe something similar can be done here. Were you able to find anything else on the bottom equation?

@ТymaGaidash Because I'm interested in such solutions: Is there a way to transform $xe^{P_1(x)}=c_1$ into $P_2(t)e^t=c_2$ or vice versa?

@ТymaGaidash I found this similar answer, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4936798/solve-for-y-in-ye-frac12y-frac1y-x, mentioning the "Burniston-Siewert method to solve transcendental equations". However I am not really familiar with the technique, so I still have to figure out if it can be applied to my instance.

@EmFed It looks like a complicated technique, but seems to be able to be applied to most equations. Maybe the user from there can answer.

We have to differentiate between closed-form solutions and analytic solutions.
a) Let $P(x)$ denote a polynomial in $x$.
$$xe^{P(x)}=c$$
It seems the equation is solvable by Lambert W only if $P(x)=a_0+a_1x^b\  $ ($a_0,a_1,b$ constant).
$$xe^{a_0+a_1x^b}=c\tag{1}$$
The solution for real $a_0,a_1,b,x$ is:
$$x=e^\frac{-a_0b+b\ln(c)-W_k\left(a_1be^{-a_0b+b\ln(c)}\right)}{b}\ \ (k\in\{-1,0\})\tag{2}$$
If we already have a solution, we can apply the operations performed on the right-hand side of equation (1) $(c)$ in reverse order to retrace the solution way:
Solving equation (2) for the $W$-term yields:
$$W_k\left(a_1be^{-a_0b+b\ln(c)}\right)=-a_0b+b\ln(c)-b\ln(x)$$
$$-a_0b+b\ln(c)-b\ln(x)=W_k\left(a_1be^{-a_0b+b\ln(c)}\right)\tag{3}$$
We know: $xe^x=c\implies x=W(c)$ and $x=W(c)\implies xe^x$.
Equation (3) implies therefore:
$$(-a_0b+b\ln(c)-b\ln(x))e^{-a_0b+b\ln(c)-b\ln(x)}=a_1be^{-a_0b+b\ln(c)}\tag{4}$$
See the operations at $c$ on the right-hand side of equation (4).
$$xe^{a_0+a_1x^b}=c$$
$$\ln(xe^{a_0+a_1x^b})=\ln(c)$$
$$\ln(x)+a_0+a_1x^b=\ln(c)$$
$$b\ln(x)+a_0b+a_1bx^b=b\ln(c)$$
$$a_1bx^b+b\ln(x)=-a_0b+b\ln(c)$$
$$x^be^{a_1bx^b}=e^{-a_0b+b\ln(c)}$$
$$a_1bx^be^{a_1bx^b}=a_1be^{-a_0b+b\ln(c)}$$
$$a_1bx^b=W_k\left(a_1be^{-a_0b+b\ln(c)}\right)$$
$$x^b=\frac{W_k\left(a_1be^{-a_0b+b\ln(c)}\right)}{a_1b}$$
$$e^{b\ln(x)}=\frac{W_k\left(a_1be^{-a_0b+b\ln(c)}\right)}{a_1b}$$
$$\ln(e^{b\ln(x)})=\ln\left(\frac{W_k\left(a_1be^{-a_0b+b\ln(c)}\right)}{a_1b}\right)$$
$\ln(W(y))=\ln(y)-W(y)$:
$$b\ln(x)=-a_0b+b\ln(c)-W_k\left(a_1be^{-a_0b+b\ln(c)}\right)$$
$$\ln(x)=\frac{-a_0b+b\ln(c)-W_k\left(a_1be^{-a_0b+b\ln(c)}\right)}{b}$$
$$x=e^{\frac{-a_0b+b\ln(c)-W_k\left(a_1be^{-a_0b+b\ln(c)}\right)}{b}}$$
$\ $
b) For applying Lambert W, we need the equation in a form
$$f(g(x)e^{g(x)})=c,$$
where $f$ and $g$ are functions of one variable. But with the elementary operations (are elementary functions), it's only possible for relatively simple functions of $x$ in the coefficient and in the exponent to make the coefficient and the exponent equal.
